# Team City Code Coverage includes excluded code in total

Tags: statistics, teamcity, metrics, dotcover

We have this issue with the Code Coverage in Team City (using dotCover).
In the the coverage of statements, the percentage is calculated as `covered/Total`.
Which is good.

When we exclude neamespaces (e.g. the test code and 3rd party products), the excluded namespaces are still listed but with the `covered` metric is 0 (zero) which is what to expect.

However, the `Total` metric is **not** zero for excluded namespaces and is included in the overall `Total` metric. This scews the coverage metrics!

Screenshot of the problem:

[image]

How do I get around this?
(This is TC 7.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

Move 3rd party code into separated assembly.